# Trying to run grunt task cssmin and getting this error : TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'isAbsolute'

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

TypeError: Object # has no method 'isAbsolute'

```
cssmin: {
            target: {
                src: ["styles/css/main.css"],
                dest: "styles/css/main.min.css"
            }
        }
```

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44794105/grunt-task-uglify-errors-typeerror-object-object-has-no-method-isabsolut

Comment: @Christoph: I tried that but same issue. node is updated already.

Comment: Install an earlier version of `grunt-contrib-cssmin`. Firstly uninstall the current version `$ npm un -D grunt-contrib-cssmin` then install version _1.0.1_ of the plugin: `$ npm i -D grunt-contrib-cssmin@1.0.1`. Grunt should run successfully after that.